# Opening file:///c:/ Urls from IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, webbrowser-control

I have not been able to get cross-protocol links from http:// to file:// URLs to work from IE 11.  Yes, I know this is disabled by default, but I am trying this because I have customers who say it works for them and I'm trying to assess why it works for them in IE 11 and not when they use our hosted WebBrowser control.

From what I understand this should be possible from Intranet Zone URLs although I see conflicting information about what it takes, here's what I've tried:

- Windows 10 running latest IE 11
- The source URL is http://devtest/test/testlink.html
- It has a link to file:///c:/temp/test.html
- Clicking on the link fails silently
- I have added devtest to the intranet zone and the Properties show that it is in the intranet zone.
- I have disabled protected mode
- I have enabled "Access data sources across domains"
- I have even added FEATURE_BLOCK_CROSS_PROTOCOL_FILE_NAVIGATION  / iexplore.exe DWORD 0
- I have tried compatibility view mode

I see where EricLaw of Microsoft posted that this should work from IE 11 (https://textslashplain.com/2019/10/09/navigating-to-file-urls/), but it's still failing silently for me.

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

I have checked it in IE, Microsoft Edge ( the Legacy version and the New Microsoft Edge) and  the Chrome Browser, they all block to open the local file using `file:///` path.

As [the document](https://textslashplain.com/2019/10/09/navigating-to-file-urls/) said, using `file:///` retrieves content can result in privacy and security problems. If you want to see the local file, I suggest you could copy (right click the `file:///` link and select 'Copy Shortcut') and paste the link into the URL address directly.

Comment: But that same document also says that this will work in IE if the navigation is from an Intranet URL which is my question, not whether it's a good idea or not, but how to make it actually work in IE as stated.  And I'm pretty confident that as EricLaw said, it used to work in IE some time back.

Comment: I also note and check it, but unfortunately, IE browser still blocks the file:// link on an https-delivered webpage. But, if we click the file:// link from a local webpage (using IE browser open local html page, the IE browser URL address like : C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\example\filelink.html), the file:// link works well. So, in my opinion, for the https-delivered webpage, I suggest you could copy and paste the link into the url address.